# Build / Destroy function design & security checks

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a browser based strategy game. For the moment I'm working on the build/destroy functions and I have a couple of questions about this. The main question is do you have advice on how I can pass the buildingId and townId to the page where I call the build function? Any advices about the checking I should have in the build / destroy function?

Comment: Morning? It's nearly time to call it a day here... :)

Comment: :-) it's 9:33 am here :-) for me the day started today at 7:30 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is PHP, you can pass your buildingId and townId as GET data in the URL, i.e.:

```
build.php?building=39&town=204832
```

You can then access this with `$_GET["building"]` and `$_GET["town"]`, which would equal 39 and 204832 respectively in this case.

Your other option is submitting this as POST data (form data) and accessing it using `$_POST["building"]`. I don't know of a way in PHP to send POST data other than to have form fields on your page and submit that form (`<input type="hidden">` would come in handy here). The only advantage here is that your variables aren't exposed in the URL, but it is does not make anything more secure.

I am not a security expert, but don't trust any information your client gives you. There are a lot of security checks you might want to do and only you (as the game's designer) would know which ones need to be asked. Some likely examples:

- Does the town exist and belong to the user, or do they have permission to build there?
- Does the building they want to build even exist? Can they build it? Can they build it *there*? If it is a one-of-a-kind building, have they already built it?
- Is there already something built there? Is there room for it?

---

My ultimate advice would also be that **you should not use PHP at all**, and instead should create this game in *anything else*: Python webservice, ASP.NET, JavaServer Pages, take your pick. [PHP is an incredibly bad language](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) in all the ways a language can be bad. This is not me having a language bias and hating on a language like how some people hate C++ or Java. This is different.  *PHP is actually just bad.*

Comment: i was looking for new ideeas how to parse the building id and town id so i can go further for inserts, updates, data check and other things like that, and few ideeas about what should i check see if my list is fine or not :) and it is :-D thank you very much for  your reply and for the next replies will come during this day :-)

Comment: i'm using pdo driver for the database work related :-)

Comment: Nevermind then, prepared statements with PDO will do well

Comment: yes i know :-) so far so good yet i'm sad because of all the checkings i need to do some queries to the db :-( and i was hoping to keep it as simple as posible and with a max of three queries :)